# How to add 1 week baseInterval for axisRange in amCharts v4, to delete wrong stroke line?

Tags: amcharts, amcharts4

I see wrong stroke lines when my data set has only 1 week for each month

[image]

i use baseInterval in categoryAxis to hide empty data

```
            categoryAxis.baseInterval = {
                timeUnit: "week",
                count: 1
            };
```

So baseInterval removes empty dates and grid space, but seems axisRanges doesn't have same baseInterval property...

i create each new month range via function below

```
    createRange(from: any, to: any, label: any, rotation: any, parentSize: number, showAdditionalLabelStroke?: any) {
        let range = this.chart.xAxes.values[0].axisRanges.create();
        range.date = from;
        range.endDate = to;
        range.label.text = label;
        range.grid.strokeOpacity = true;
    }
```

if i remove baseInterval from the categoryAxis, axisRanges stroke lines became correct but then i have got wrong labels:

tooltip shows 26 week, categoryAxis shows 22 week, tooltip shows 30 week, categoryAxis shows 26 week and so on...

So this image is expected result (but it has wrong categoryAxis labels)
[image]